# New sharepoint environment and data connection b/w sharepoint webpart does not work

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I do not see any Connection Configure dialog popping up when I try connecting 2 webparts.

I even tried using designer to connect webpart even though it gives me confirmation it does not appear to have been connected.... I am totally clueless.

Comment: Are these built-in webparts, or webparts you have created?

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same problem.

Eventually found out, that the possibility to connect webparts to each other (via UI) is gone when you're using rich text pages; pages without webpart zones. As soon as I added webpart zones to a page, the possibility returned.

This may be a bug in SP2010, or is it a feature...?

Comment: Its not a bug. Web part zones are more than simple containers. Placing a web part in a zone associates the web part to a web part manager. This in turn enables the moving/editing/connecting   of the web part from the browser. Web parts placed outside zones behave like normal web controls and cannot be  edited from  browser.